# Use EXISTS with derived table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012, subquery, exists

```
SELECT *
FROM 
( SELECT ID, Name
  FROM ....
) AS DT
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM DT AS DT2 WHERE DT.ID=DT2.ID AND DT2.Name='A')
```

Trying to use a Derived table DT in an existential subquery but getting the error:

> Invalid object name 'DT'

Does the scope of a derived table not extend to an existential subquery?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The scope extend to the inner subquery, but you are trying to clone the table.

In the `exists ()` you could use  `( SELECT ID, Name  FROM .... ) AS DT` but is better using `WITH`

```
WITH cte as ( 
       SELECT ID, Name
       FROM ....
) 
SELECT *
FROM cte as DT
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 
                  FROM cte AS DT2 
                  WHERE DT.ID=DT2.ID 
                    AND DT2.Name='A')
```

**Suggestion**: As you can see the scope of `DT` like `DT.id` will work, the problem is you try to clone the derivated table and you cant. Behind door this is exactly what `CTE` does.

```
SELECT *
FROM ( SELECT ID, Name
       FROM ....) as DT
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 
                  FROM ( SELECT ID, Name
                         FROM ....) AS DT2 
                  WHERE DT.ID=DT2.ID 
                    AND DT2.Name='A')
```

Comment: Is there an alternative way to achieve this besides CTE? I am aware of this technique but was exploring the alternative based on a limitation at my end. The actual derived table code is much bigger and reusing it inside Exists would make the code huge.

Comment: Yes, I explain it here. You need to rewrite the `DT` query inside the `exists`. what is your limitation?

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza +1 bien hecho

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza I also have a web based sql server based tool which doesn't let me begin queries with anything besides `SELECT`. So it doesn't let me use CTE's in the format it accepts.

Comment: I see, then you understand why you cant do what you suggest? You need to duplicate the code for `DT` check update.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need `exists` at all.  You can use window functions:

```
SELECT ID, Name
FROM (SELECT ID, Name,
             SUM(CASE WHEN DT2.Name = 'A' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) OVER (PARTITION BY ID) as a_cnt
      FROM ....
     ) DT
WHERE a_cnt = 0;
```

Comment: As usual while I just answer the question you go very depth and solve the problem. Any reason why you use `SUM()` instead of `COUNT()`. I rather use `COUNT()` when you are obviously counting.

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza . . . First, because some databases support constructs such as `sum(DT2.Name = 'A')` -- a very nice shorthand.  Second, because `count(2)` returns the same value as `count(1)` and I find that misleading.